# How to check if there are some some characters left in stdin after scanf?

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

```
scanf("%9s", line);
```

I read a line from stdin (max 9 symbols) and after that I want to check if I read all the characters from user input. Is there any elegant way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `feof()`?

Comment: Do you mean feof(stdin)? I just tried it and it returns 0 no matter what length string I input

Comment: '`feof(stdin)`' returns 0 no matter what length string I input' — which tells you that there's a newline left to be read by the next I/O operation...  The only time there won't be any data left is if you encounter EOF without a final newline.

Comment: actually there are some implementations of stdin that do not work and will result in 0 all the time regardless of actual content on the stream.

Answer (score 3):

`feof()` will allow you to check if the stdin buffer is empty. Else if you want to go further and check the contents ...use something like this..

```
while ( fgets(buf,BUFSIZ,stdin) != NULL ) 
  {     printf("%s",buf); }
```

Here buf will be the array/string to hold BUFSIZ bytes of data

Comment: feof() keeps returning 0. Perhaps I am reading the string in a bad way? Could you an example of how to get feof() to be not equal to one after reading everything from it?

Comment: In the console you have to press <Ctrl-D> (Linux) to make feof() return 1. Maybe sth. like select(), poll(), ... can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend separating human input from parsing.  Folks enter the most unexpected characters. and invariable I find it easier to correctly handle these issues separately.

Read in the line  (this I put in its own function)

```
char buf[1024];
char *retval;
retval = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
// if I/O trouble reading ...
if (!retval) {
  handle error
} 
// if End-of-line missing (as buffer was filled) ...
if (!strchr(buf, '\n')) {
  handle error
} 
// Toss '\n'
buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
```

Then parse the data

```
sscanf(buf, "%9s", line); 
if (strlen(buf) > 9) {
  // You have extra data
  }
```

Comment: You could use `if ((retval = strchr(buf, '\n')) == 0) { ...handle error... } *retval = '\0';` avoiding a second scan of the input string when you already know where the newline is.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler is certainly correct.  Usually I do this the other way around, find the string length, see if it is > 0, and then if the last char is a \n, delete it.  But that approach looks less clear.

Comment: Yup: you can use either `strlen()` or `strchr()`, but you shouldn't need to use both in this context.  But the general approach is correct; `fgets()` plus analysis is generally better.  Even so, `feof()` won't return true until `fgets()` has returned 0.  It doesn't know when the next read will return nothing; it knows when the last read did return nothing.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I've had simialr foef() issues.  Another use of input & parsing separation:  Should a given parsing fail, one can readily try another parsing.  E.g. reading a textual boolean that evaluates to true: it could be "T", "True", "1".  It might need a more complicated parse what the scanf() function family provides.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the data into a bigger string first and afterwards get its length.
At some point you want to just get rid of whatever is left on the input buffer.
To do that you can use fflush on some systems and fpurge on all the others.

Here is some sample code that you could use to fill up a big buffer and just purge the rest. The cleaning function will remove the final newline or end the string early if any special characters are in it.

```
void userInput( char * str, int size );
void get( char * str, int size );  
void clean( char * str, int size );  
void flush( void );

void userInput( char * str, int size )
{
    get( str, size );
    clean( str, size );   
    flush();
}

void get( char * str, int size )
{
    memset( str, 0, size );
    fgets ( str, size, stdin );
}

void clean( char * str, int size )
{
    char * c;   
    str [size -1] = 0;
    c = str;
    while( *c >= ' ' || *c < 0 ) ++c;
    *c = 0;
}

void flush( void )
{
    //the ifdef approach does not work in reality.
    //this is a pseudo case for your benefit.
    #ifdef fpurge 
        fpurge(stdin);
    #else
        fflush(stdin);
    #endif
}
```